# Latest Eclipse update causes errors?

Tags: android, eclipse

today I've updated my Eclipse (Win7 x86_64) with latest android updates and it caused some errors. First of all, after cleaning project Eclipse didn't generate R files. I've tried to find any possible error in my xml files, although - there was none. I've copied my project and opened it with Eclipse without latest updates on Arch Linux - Eclipse generated R file and everything was OK. I think that's also important to mention, that after updating Eclipse on Windows the new code, that I've written didn't work - worked perfectly on Linux's instance. I've copied all R files and folders to Windows, yet couldn't run app, because my apk was missing and after that I've just gave up.
Anyone had similar problems or is there any possible solution?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: There is none. After cleaning project it just didn't generate R files - I've spent at least hour to look for the problem, then I've imported my project on Linux Eclipse w/o latest update and it generated R properly. So I've copied R to Windows Eclipse, but after that I had error with launching app 'couldn't find MyAppName.apk'.

Comment: Please don't say: "The latest updates".  This will be viewed in the future by other people, and thus "The latest" is a word that becomes meaningless.  Leaving "yahoo answers" like useless garbage-artefacts all over stack overflow.  Please stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had experienced the same. For the new SDK(ver 22.0.1), we need to install a new tool Android SDK Build Tools.

After that, update the eclipse ADT.

Restart the eclipse. 
Then clean and run the project.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience some versions back. The work-around I found was to setup an entirely new and separate IDE instance including a different SDK folder location. Install from scratch! Good luck ...

Comment: Well, I've got exact problem on another PC, but still using 64bit win 7 and STS (eclipse) with latest android updates, so I guess there should be any possible solution